# Word table options greyed out

Tags: microsoft-word, table-styles

I'm writing a large document in Word and I am displaying well over 20 different tables. Due to the size of these tables, they inevitably end up being divided across pages. I obviously want to keep a table to a page completely. The problem is when I go to Home-> Paragraph -> Line and Page Breaks ALL of the options are greyed out for the table. What is happening and how do In un-grey them?

Cant post an image to show you so I hope I'm being descriptive enough.

[image]

EDIT 1: The word version is 2010. The tables were created using the Insert Table GUI. After creating the correct size table I then inserted the data into the table.

EDIT 2: Still having this problem. Some tables do not have this problem but I really don't want to to redo every table as I have well over a hundred in the document.

Comment: Post an image - much better than description, always

Comment: What version of Word are you using? Is the file read only? How were the tables created? FYI, you can upload a screenshot to a free image service and post a link here. We will add it to your post for you.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely you have opened a document with restricted editing. Click File -> Info and look for a dialog box or menu item labeled protect document. It should display a message if the document is restricted in some way. Unless you are the original document creator you likely won't be able to un-restrict the document, you'll need to create a new one.